# ToggleButton в ActionBar

Tags: android, actionbar

Реализовал `ToggleButton` в `ActionBar`, но есть проблема
В `ActionBar` при запуске активности иконку видно не сразу, сначала видно значение `Share`
Можно ли сделать так, чтобы появлялась сразу иконка?
Вот код:
1. Меню:

```
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_toogle"
        android:title="Share"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

</menu>
```

2. Код:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_read, menu);
        return true;
    }
    boolean birthSort=false;
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_toogle:

                if(birthSort){
                    item.setIcon(R.drawable.toggle_off);
                    birthSort=false;
                }else{
                    item.setIcon(R.drawable.toggle_on);
                    birthSort=true;
                }
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Если поменять значение `app:showAsAction="ifRoom"` на `always`, то это ничего не меняет
Если значение `android:title="Share"` оставить пустым, то вообще ничего нет, пока не нажмешь на это место, потом появится иконка

Comment: видимо вам надо устанавливать свою иконку при создании меню, в onCreateOptionsMenu(), так она у вас и будет появляться только при нажатии, так как устанавливается в onOptionsItemSelected() - реакция на нажатие пункта меню. А вообще лучше [установить сам виджет](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12107031/7566397), а не его симуляцию картинками

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, сделал все, сейчас добавлю свой ответ, может пригодится кому

Answer (score 0):

Решение:

```
    private Menu menu;
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        this.menu = menu;
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_read, menu);
        menu.getItem(0).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.toggle_off));
        return true;
    }
    boolean birthSort=false;
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_toogle:

                if(birthSort){
                    item.setIcon(R.drawable.toggle_off);
                    birthSort=false;
                }else{
                    item.setIcon(R.drawable.toggle_on);
                    birthSort=true;
                }
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```